# REPAST HPC WSL Installation leads to boost no being found

Tags: repast-hpc

When trying to run Repast HPC executables I get the following error:

`./main.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_mpi-mt.so.1.61.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ./main.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_mpi-mt.so.1.61.0: cannot open shared object`

In the make file I define the link to boost in an `env` file with the below:

```
BOOST_INCLUDE= -I$(HOME)/sfw/Boost/Boost_1.61/include/
BOOST_LIB_DIR= -L$(HOME)/sfw/Boost/Boost_1.61/lib/
```

This is linked to a make file with the following make file

```
include ./env

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.exe

.PHONY: compile
compile:
    $(MPICXX) $(BOOST_INCLUDE) -c Main.cpp -o Main.o
    $(MPICXX) $(BOOST_LIB_DIR) -o main.exe Main.o $(BOOST_LIBS)

.PHONY: all
all: clean compile
```

Boost in `tsnow@DESKTOP-IF7CEHL:~/sfw/Boost/Boost_1.61/lib$` so it should link well across.

Any help appreciated, just trying to get a tutorial running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We typically don't link repast to boost, but rather use rpath to let the model executable know where the boost and repast libraries are. For example in your Makefile:

```
REPAST_LIB_DIR = $(REPAST_HOME)/lib
BOOST_LIB_DIR = $(HOME)/theta/sfw/boost-1.66.0/lib
RPATHS += -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(REPAST_LIB_DIR) -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(BOOST_LIB_DIR)
```

and then add $(RPATHS) after the list of libraries during linking.

```
model : $(EXEC_OBJECTS)
    $(CXXLD) -fopenmp -dynamic $^ $(LIBS) $(RPATHS) -o $(NAME)
```

Some of those args might not be appropriate for WSL, but hopefully the RPATHS part makes sense.

So, if after your include directive, you add

```
RPATHS=-Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(BOOST_LIB_DIR)
```

and update the second line of your compile target with

```
$(MPICXX) $(BOOST_LIB_DIR) -o main.exe Main.o $(BOOST_LIBS) $(RPATHS)
```

The location of your boost libs is compiled into main.exe, and it should find it.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/tsnow/sfw/Boost/Boost_1.61/lib/`

allowed boost to be found.

Comment: I also updated my answer to show how to update your Makefile to use rpath.